# Multiple Servers, externally, through single IP

Tags: windows, networking, routing, nat, isa

Let's say, I have a server that is directly connected to the internet (no firewall), and sits on 66.77.88.99 externally, and internally sits on 192.168.0.1. I have my domain's records set up so that mydomain.com points to my external IP.

I also have another server, which sits on 192.168.0.2, but is only accessible internally, as I only have 1 external IP address. I have forwarded server2.mydomain.com to my external IP, but of course, it points to my first server.

Is there a way, to possibly route the traffic coming from server2.mydomain.com to the other server?
I have been reading about this, but it's not very clear, using Microsoft ISA Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.vaas.me/?p=14

You can set a third server as a gateway (reverse proxy) with apache that will take your single ip and depending on the domain, will forward to a different internal IP.

Comment: Any way to do this with IIS?

Comment: Nevermind, got it all sorted, what I need is a reverse proxy. Thanks so much. (I can't vote up, not enought reputation)